Set git environment variables in vscode
I use vscode with remote SSH. When commiting it uses server git config; I want to override this for my user/session. I think the easiest way is to set "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" and "GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" environment variables for git.
PS: I cannot use "git config" because it is a shared server/account/repo.

Setting:
    "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false,
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME": "aaa",
        "GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL": "aaa@example.com",
    },


in settings.json seems to have solved my problem.
